# Lucene multiple indexes : Normalize document scores?

Tags: c#, lucene

Suppose I've got multiple lucene indexes (not replicas) on several PC's.

I query each index and then merge the results. 
Is there any way to normalize the document scores so that I could sort by score (relevance)?

I mean, the scores for document A from index A would not be comparable with document B from index B, unless I do some sort of normalization.... not so?

Thanks
Roey

Answer (score 4):

First, study the [Lucene Similarity Documentation](http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_4_0/api/all/org/apache/lucene/search/Similarity.html). Out of all the factors there, the only one that is different from one index to another is the [inverse document frequency (idf)](http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_4_0/api/all/org/apache/lucene/search/Similarity.html#formula_idf).

I suggest you use [Luke](http://code.google.com/p/luke/) or a debugger to see the impact of the different indexes' idfs.
You may find that this only has a minor influence.

Here is [a discussion about using a global idf](http://www.lucidimagination.com/search/document/7b9fe933e3590270/idf_in_distributed_search#7b9fe933e3590270), and here - a [Wiki page about distributed search design in Solr](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DistributedSearchDesign). I believe the problem is not yet solved.

The Lucene scoring does not lend itself to simple normalization. I suggest you try and make the document distribution as random as possible, and then compare how your hits from the two indexes rank.

Comment: +1 to randomly distribute the documents.  You have to make sure this is indeed a problem.  In most cases, the different DF values between the indexes won't really hurt you.

Comment: I realise this is an old answer, but just letting you know some links are broken

Comment: @AndyMcCluggage - I have updated the broken links to the current Lucene version. That should give you a year or so, until Lucene versions supersede the current one.

Answer (score -1):

for comparing the score of document A for indices X and Y. I compute `x = score(A,X) / max score of any document that is a hit for search on index X` and `y = score(A,Y) / max score of any document that is a hit for search on index Y`.

Both x and y are now between 0 and 1. just add x and y to get the final score.

this is a naive approach. would like to hear your comments on this.

but i don't understand why do you want to add scores of two different documents. Use Case?

Comment: I believe you misunderstood the question. The question was how to normalize scores across result sets, which would be useful for performing a search across a bunch of indexes and displaying the most relevant results. The concern is that the contents of each index influences the scoring of results. If index X has a low frequency of keyword "motorcycle", it might score a doc containing that keyword highly. When merging an identical search against index Y, which let's say has a high frequency of that keyword, the docs from X might be scored higher than potentially more relevant docs from Y.